# Personal workspace was overwritten after upgrading to Eclipse Oxygen.1

Tags: windows, eclipse, upgrade, administrator

I have just proceed to update my current Eclipse *Oxygen* installation to the latest versions (including *Oxygen.1*). As I did before (with previous *Neon* iterations for example), I have launched Eclipse using the **administrator mode** on Windows.

After updating all the componants, when I restart using the **normal mode**, all the settings I have made in my own workspace seems to have be fully overwritten: it now looks like the default workspace.

I don't understand if I have made something wrongly or if there have been a bug during the upgrade process, but I would want to know if there is a way to retrieve my previous workspace and to prevent this kind of behaviour.

Comment: If you do it the way you did it, you have to use a new workspace for it.I guess some files in your workspace are now unreadable and/or writeable without admin rights.

Comment: If I understand your comment, would that mean that I should not have used the **administrator mode**? However, some updates only seem to be available once that Eclipse has been opened as administrator...

Comment: If this is the cause (running in administrator mode will look like reverting the overwrite), it would have been better to use a temporary workspace for updating. The recommended way is to install Eclipse in the user area, so that no admin rights are required for an update.